# Sum over characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Take $x>0$ large, $t\in \mathbb R$, $q\in \mathbb N$ and a non-principal character $\chi $ mod $q$.  If you want, take $t\leq x$.  How do I bound

\[ \sum _{n\leq x}\frac {\chi (n)}{n^{it}}?\]

My guess was that this is $\ll \sqrt {qt}$, based on thinking about the $q=1$ case, which is the relatively well known statement

\[ \sum _{n\leq x}\frac {1}{n^{it}}=\text {main term }+\mathcal O\left (1\right ).\]

Euler-Maclaurin and Polya-Vinogradov shows the sum in question to be $\ll t\sqrt q$, which is too weak.  But in the $q=1$ case EM may be combined with Van der Corput's summation formula to get an $\mathcal O(1)$ bound.  If I try to replicate that argument, I get stuck since I don't know how to bound (for $a\in \mathbb N$ with $(a,q)=1$)

\[ \int _x^\infty \frac {e(ua/q)du}{u^{it}}\]

One idea would be with complex analysis: Perron's formula says for some $c>1$ and any $T>0$ the sum is (the error terms really only being "essentially" as small as stated)

$$\int _{c\pm iT}\frac {L_{\chi }(s+it)ds}{s}+\mathcal O\left (x/T\right )$$

where by the Residue Theorem the main term is, for some $0<c'<1$,

$$\int _{c'\pm iT}\frac {L_{\chi }(s+it)x^sds}{s}
+\int _{c'+iT}^{c+iT}\frac {L_{\chi }(s+it)x^sds}{s}+(\text { similar integral }).$$

Taking absolute values gives a total error something like $$\ll x/T+\sqrt (T+|t|)$$ which is also too large.  But explicitly computing the vertical integral via the functional equation seems to get better bounds, and give my required result.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using van der Corput, why don't you express the sum as a complex integral?

To simplify matters, consider a smooth sum, i.e.,
$$S(x,t) = \sum_n f(n/x) n^{-i t},$$
where $f$ is fixed $C^\infty$ function of compact support (though of course much weaker conditions suffice), with $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$, say, so that you are studying essentially the same sum as before. Then
$$S(x,t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} x^s M f(s) L(s+i t,\chi) ds$$
for $\sigma>1$.

Now displace the integral all the way to the left of the $y$-axis. You'll pick up a pole at $s=0$ (coming from $M f(s)$). Bound $|L(i t)|$ using the functional equation and the bound $|L(1+ i t,\chi)|\ll \log q t$ (valid for $|t|\gg 1$; see, e.g., Montgomery-Vaughan, Thm. 11.4). There is indeed a factor of essentially $\sqrt{q t}$ coming from the functional equation. The dominant term of the bound will thus be $O(\sqrt{q t} \log q t)$.

(If we knew $L(s,\chi)$ has no real zeroes $\sigma$ with $\sigma>1/2$, it would be $O(\sqrt{q t} \log \log q t)$, by the bound in op. cit., exercise 13.2.6.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But I need it without a smooth weight. (With a smooth weight I agree I can get the required bounds.)

Comment: Then do it without a smooth weight, using Perron's formula. (I was avoiding inessential complications, admittedly very minor ones - or non-existent - in this case.)

Comment: But always ask yourself: do I really need a smooth weight? People often don't. ("Smoothing is given by nature.")

Comment: Without a smooth weight I can't get the said bounds, and that's the difficulty.  (Bounding the various contour integrals in Perron's formula will always cost something like $x^{1/4}$, I think, since without a weight I have the integrand  $L(s+it)x^s/s$ compared to $L(s+it)x^s/s(s+1) $ with a smooth weight.)

Comment: Then try using a smooth weight that is a very close approximation to a brutal one (enough that the error incurred in the approximation is smaller than what you want). The decay will have to be slow at first, so make $T$ large enough (are you choosing $T$ optimally, anyhow?).

Comment: I'll have a think about this.. thank you :) (choosing T: you mean T as a parameter in the perron argument? There I choose it optimally to get the above  $x^{1/4} $ bound)

Comment: I just carried out a back-of-the-envelope calculation and I'm not seeing $x^{1/4}$. Double-check - if it keeps coming up, tell us why. I think it's purely technical, however.

Comment: I've edited the question so as to check whether I'm doing this correctly.  You mean to say I can choose in my analysis above simply $T=t$ for example?

Comment: I get a term $x^s$ inside the integral (see my answer), so it would make sense to let $T$ depend on $x$ as well. Also, be careful with the bound $|L(\sigma+it)|\ll \sqrt{q t}$: on the one hand, things might get a tiny bit worse for $\sigma\to 0^+$ (otherwise said: the implied constant could depend on $\sigma$, though nowhere close to disastrously); on the other hand, for $\sigma$ away from $0$, you get a considerably better bound. Use that fact to counterbalance $x^s$.

Comment: Ah yes forgot to write the $x^s$.  In my actual application I actually have $n^{\sigma +it}$ for $\sigma $ fixed positive and close to 0.  In any case this discussion has helped me a lot, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I think I've managed it now.  If you're interested, I've edited the original post to include the important step.

Comment: Nice. I think it would be clearer if you wrote up your own answer, rather than mixing it with the question.